# How to show discount price in Play Store, Android

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I have a InApp Subscription for my app and it is published in Play Store. Now, We took a decision to give discount for that particular InApp Subscription.

We want to show user that we are giving discount for this Subscription. Here, User should know that earlier price was $ 1.99 and Now it is $ 0.99.

Presently Play Store showing like below when user trying do Subscribe

[image]

Here is my expected out put like below. Please help me.

[image]

Comment: Why do you think this is possible? Have you seen some app do this etc?

Comment: @Okas No , I have not see for Subscription. But I saw it at https://play.google.com/store/books/details/How_To_Books_Home_Remedies_Discount_Vitamins?id=VY5ZBgAAQBAJ

Comment: But if you click buy button there payment screen opens without discount information. The same way you can show this discount information in your app "subscribe button" but you can not change purchase screen. I guess for security reasons you do not have any control over purchase screen ui.

Comment: @Okas Can we add multiple subscriptions for single app ?

Comment: Of course you can - it's totally up to you to decide what in-app purchase items and subscriptions actually mean.